# How to alter contents of the XHR object returned to Angular application from the middleware in C#?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, xmlhttprequest, middleware

I have a middleware that handles the errors. It works as supposed to, including hte feature of correlation ID letting me communicate to the browser a GUID that I also print in the logs to quickly locate the exception.

```cs
    public class ExceptionWare(RequestDelegate Next, ILogger<ExceptionWare> Logger)
    {
      public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext http)
      {
        try { await Next(http); }
        catch (HttpException exception)
        {
          Guid corrId = Guid.NewGuid();
          Logger.LogError(exception, ErrorTemplate, corrId);

          http.Response.StatusCode = exception.StatusCode;
          await http.Response.WriteAsync($"corrId: {corrId}");
        }
        catch (Exception exception) { ... }
      }
    }
```

The thing is that the correlation ID is delivered in the body of the response (purple arrow). I'd like to have it as a field of the error object delivered to my Angular application (yellow arrow). In there, I'm reading the status (set in the middy above), the message (set automagically somehow in my response) and some other fields.

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.error(err.corrId); // this is my desire
        console.log(err.status);
        console.log(err.message);
        throw err;
      }));
  }
}
```

I'd like to amend that with `corrId` for ease of use **without** reading from the body. Right now, in my browser, I have to click around in the XHR response and pick the *body* tag.

[image]

After a few hours of googling, all I found was immense amounts of articles on altering the headers and/or writing to the response body. The former is of no interest to me and the latter is what I'm trying to improve.

I do carry a slight but growing feat that it's simply not achievable due to the limitation of the XHR object delivered to the browser. However, googling that angle, I haven't found anything at all that would indicate either way.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to put it if _not_ in the body or the headers? If you just want to _access_ the body, read the docs: https://angular.io/guide/http-handle-request-errors

Comment: @I'd like it to be provided the same way as the other fields I mention: `status`. `statusText` and `message`. Those, I don't set explicitly in the middleware (except the status code but it's done in another way than writing to the body of the response). It sounds on you comment that it's not doable.

Comment: The err is Angular's [HttpErrorResponse](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpErrorResponse) (as you've literally written in your code) which is (like "the XHR object") a representation of an HTTP response. So if you think you can persuade the IETF that the whole HTTP specification needs changing to add correlation IDs to responses, then wait for that to get rolled out globally and for Angular and whatever C# library (and your browser!) to update their representations' APIs accordingly, then it's totally doable. Or you could just read the body you've already got (or use a header).

Comment: I can be quite persuasive, you know... And both Google and Microsoft listens to the developers' needs. However, I don't trust those Norwegian dude with their Opera browser, so I'll choose not to push this issue. (On a serious note, I guess, I felt somewhere deep inside that it was a no-go but I didn't want to be arrogant and make a judgement call "*can't be done*" based on "***me** not knowing*". Thanks for the input.)